# Spring MVC interpretting object binding as string

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am trying to create a Spring Form with a dropdown of all the user's reports, but the jsp page is interpreting my object binding as a string. I have been struggling with this for a while and am currently using an inline script to print the results instead, but would much prefer using the object binding.

view.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@page
    import="com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.Report, java.util.*"%>


<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="reportView" action="">
        <form:label path="defaultName.value">Name</form:label>
        <form:input path="defaultName.value"/><br/>
        <form:label path="base">Report Name</form:label>
        <form:select path="base">
        <form:options items="${reports}" itemValue="defaultName" itemLabel="defaultName" />
        <%
            //List<Report> reportList = (List)request.getAttribute("reports");
            //for (Report r : reportList) {
            //  out.print("<option value=");
            //  out.print(r);
            //  out.println(">" + r +"</option>");
            //}
        %>
        </form:select>
        <form:label path="disabled.value">Disabled?</form:label>
        <form:checkbox path="disabled.value"/>
        <form:hidden path="searchPath.value" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Update" />
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

controller.java

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
//import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.Report;


@RequestMapping(value="/new", method=GET)
public String newView (@RequestParam("usr")String usr, Map<String, Object> model) {
    //public String newView(){
    cognos.checkConfig();
    cognos.connectToCognos(); 
    cognos.logonToCognosAsUsr(usr);
    ReportView rv = new ReportView();
    model.put("reportView", rv);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("STILL DOES NOT", "WORK");
    model.put("reports", map);
    //model.put("reports", cognos.fetchReports());
    cognos.logoffFromCognos();
    return "new_view";
}
```

CognosService.java

```
public Map<String, Report> fetchReports() {
        BaseClass bc[] = null;
        String searchPath = "/content//report";
        List<Report> rtn = new ArrayList<Report>();
        try {
            SearchPathMultipleObject spMulti =
                    new SearchPathMultipleObject(searchPath);
            bc = cmService.query(spMulti, props, new Sort[] {}, new QueryOptions());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (bc != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bc.length; i++) {
                Report r = (Report)bc[i];
                rtn.add(r);

            }
        }
        Collections.sort(rtn, new ReportComparator());
        for (Report rp : rtn){
            reportList.put(rp.getStoreID().getValue().toString(), rp);
        }
        return reportList;
    }
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

    <display-name>Report Scheduler</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>views</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>views</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

views-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.enernoc.reporting.ReportScheduler" />

<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix">
<value>/views/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Stacktrace

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /views/new_view.jsp at line 13

10:         <form:input path="defaultName.value"/><br/>
11:         <form:label path="base">Report Name</form:label>
12:         <form:select path="base">
13:         <form:options items="${reports}" itemValue="defaultName" itemLabel="defaultName" />
14:         </form:select>
15:         <form:label path="disabled.value">Disabled?</form:label>
16:         <form:checkbox path="disabled.value"/>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.views.new_005fview_jsp._jspService(new_005fview_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.writeOptions(OptionWriter.java:143)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag.writeTagContent(OptionsTag.java:157)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.views.new_005fview_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005foptions_005f0(new_005fview_jsp.java:335)
    org.apache.jsp.views.new_005fview_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fselect_005f0(new_005fview_jsp.java:296)
    org.apache.jsp.views.new_005fview_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(new_005fview_jsp.java:144)
    org.apache.jsp.views.new_005fview_jsp._jspService(new_005fview_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: I think you need set a Map to the form:options.
have a try.

Comment: @andy Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried this and it does not work. For testing purposes I have also tried making a test map<String, String> to make sure it wasn't the report object causing the problem. map<String, String> causes the same error

Comment: I have try your code and it works. You can return a list of Report and make sure defaultName is a Report field. you can just add two simple Reports in the reports

Answer (score 1):

i can not comment due to lack of reputation.
what is the return value of `cognos.getReportsList` in `model.put("reports", cognos.getReportsList);` if it is a map with key value then it works.

Comment: public List<Report> fetchReports(){...}

Comment: `reports` should be Map with id,name (value, label)

Comment: I have changed the return type. This did not work. Same error

public Map<String, Report> fetchReports() {...}

Comment: Both should be string `Map<String,String>`

Comment: I dont believe it is the Report object causing the problem because I get the same error if i make up test data as Map<String, String>. I have updated the above code to reflect this testing

Comment: i think you trying 2 solutions at a time...if you are passing Map use <form:options items="${reports}"  /> or if you passing List<Report> use  <form:options items="${reports}" itemValue="defaultName" itemLabel="defaultName" />

Comment: Nope. Same Problem. I didn't edit the code above, but i did test your idea. I'm ready to just say screw it and stick with the inline option then use a PropertyEditorSupport to solve the problem. I upvoted you so you can comment now =) Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Yea PropertyEditorSupport should do the job and propably it could be elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

Check the results:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@page
        import="com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.Report, java.util.*"%>


    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="reportView" action="">
            <form:label path="defaultName.value">Name</form:label>
            <form:input path="defaultName.value"/><br/>
            <form:label path="base">Report Name</form:label>
            <form:select path="base">
            <form:options items="${reports}" itemValue="YOUR_ID_OR_VALUE_FIELD_NAME" itemLabel="VALUE_PRESENTED_FIELD_NAME"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:label path="disabled.value">Disabled?</form:label>
            <form:checkbox path="disabled.value"/>
            <form:hidden path="searchPath.value" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Update" />
            </div>
        </form:form>
```

You need to replace **YOUR_ID_OR_VALUE_FIELD_NAME** and **YOUR_ID_OR_VALUE_FIELD_NAME** with appropriate field names from `Report` class.

Comment: I added those two attributes to the options tag. This did not fix the problem. The question has been edited to reflect this

Comment: What exaclt this `cognos.getReportsList` returns ?

Comment: I had renamed the method. That should have been the congnos.fetchReports() method I included in the code above. My apologies. public Map<String, Report> fetchReports() {}

Comment: I dont believe it is the Report object causing the problem because I get the same error if i make up test data as Map<String, String>